# Axios GET return [0, 0, 5] instead of UUIDs from database using Laravel and Vue JS

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, get, uuid

This problem looked so simple for me when I face with it  yesterday! But when I didn't find similar question on google I realized it is not as simple as what I thought!!!
So if there is any similar question that I didn't find since yesterday please let me know.
I'm trying to pass data from database using Laravel. I used UUID as primary key for Notifications table instead of auto-increment primary key (this is a default option for notifications table in Laravel!).
I can fetch and read all other columns as what they are but ID column which is UUID type comes as 0 OR 0 OR 5 or just any other single numbers however the real ID can be `1367dc99-ee67-4f0f-b0eb-c2215831d7db`.
Frankly, I have no idea what is wrong either with the method I used in the Laravel or in Vue JS axios.
Is there any specific technique that I should use to read UUIDs from backend to frontend? **Please help me with this.**
I attached codes from Laravel and Vue JS Axios down below. If there is anything missing in my question please let me know.

**Laravel Code**

```
$notifications = Notifications::where('notifiable_id', auth()->user()->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

return response()->json(
[
   "notifications" => $notifications
]
```

**Vue JS Axios GET Method**

```
data () {
   return {
      loading: false,
      unreadNotifications: []
   }
},
methods: {
  async Notifications () {
    this.loading = true
    await axios.get('/user/notifications/unreads')
        .then((response) => {
            this.unreadNotifications = response.data
        })
        .finally (() => {
            this.loading = false
        })
  }
}
```

**the output is [ 0, 5 ]**

Comment: When you `console.log(response.data.notifications)`, what is the output ?

Comment: @Atika Output is an Observer type array with value something like this
```(1) [{…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]
0: avatar: "info.png"
created_at: "2021-09-25T12:07:20.000000Z"
data: "{\"notifiable_type\":\"6d2bd7c3d7e461949f\",\"notifiable_id\":\"daniel@email.com\"}"
id: 0
message: "You account is successfully activated!"
notifiable_id: 1
notifiable_type: "App\\Models\\User"
read_at: "2021-09-25 12:07:24"
seen_at: "2021-09-25 12:07:24"
type: "verification"
updated_at: "2021-09-25T12:07:24.000000Z"
user_id: 1
length: 1
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(1), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display your `id` like this : `1367dc99-ee67-4f0f-b0eb-c2215831d7db`, then modify your query by :

```
$notifications = DB::table('notifications')
         ->where('notifiable_id', auth()->user()->id)
         ->orderByDesc('created_at')
         ->get();

return response()->json([
       "notifications" => $notifications
    ]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution and it works. Can you please also explain why the other way I used before didn't work? I'm just learning curious to know its reason!

Comment: By convention, Eloquent assumes that the primary key on a model is an incremented integer value. Since we are using UUID, we need to specify that the primary key is a string and that it is not an incremental value. For that, (if you want to use UUID with your model), I invite you to read this article: https://www.larashout.com/using-uuids-in-laravel-models

Answer (score 0):

You can use an accessor in your desired model like this:

```
public function getIdAttribute($id): string
{
     return (string)$id;
}
```

This is to make sure Laravel will return the string representation of the ID attribute.